# Service Fabric wcf communication between microservices

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I'm trying to make a simple communication between two microservices. So far as a receiver

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {

        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>
                new WcfCommunicationListener<ITest>(
                    wcfServiceObject: new Test(),
                    serviceContext: context,
                    endpointResourceName: "ProgramTestEndpoint",
                    listenerBinding: WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding()
                ),
                name: "ProgramTestListener"
            )
        };
    }

    public class Test : ITest
{
    public async Task<int> ReturnsInt()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

 [ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> ReturnsInt();


}
```

And I did add to service manifest the endpoint.

```
<Endpoint Name ="ProgramTestEndpoint"/>
```

The microservice that wants to communicate has this code

```
 protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: Replace the following sample code with your own logic 
        //       or remove this RunAsync override if it's not needed in your service.

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        CloudClient<ITest> transactionCoordinator = new CloudClient<ITest>
       (
           serviceUri: new Uri($"{Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName}/MyStateless"),
           partitionKey: new ServicePartitionKey(0),
           clientBinding: WcfUtility.CreateTcpClientBinding(),
           listenerName: "MyStateless"
       );


        int iterations = await transactionCoordinator.InvokeWithRetryAsync(client => client.Channel.ReturnsInt());
        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Test-{0}", ++iterations);
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

This is my first project in service fabric, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but with this code the application can't receive the return value of the ReturnsInt task.

Comment: What do you receive? What status code and error if any?

Comment: I tried to debug it and it seems like it can't connect to the other microservice, it look like it is stuck in an infinite loop trying to hit the method.

Comment: Would it make any difference to use `partitionKey: ServicePartitionKey.Singleton`?

Comment: @AnđelaKrstić Good guess it seems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a connection to a stateless service, you should use the `ServicePartitionKey.Singleton` partition key.  In some cases you you don't need to specify one at all, for example when using `ServiceProxyFactory` to create a connection to a stateless service.

Using `new ServicePartitionKey(0)` was causing the client to try and connect to an endpoint that didn't exist.